# VB.NET Iterating through control containers

Tags: vb.net, controls, iteration, containers

How do I go about looping through all the controls within a container, and all the controls in the container of a containing control, and so on.

```
Form
-Panel
--Control
--Tab
----Control
----Control
--Tab
----Control
```

The following only retrieves -Panel and none of the other controls

```
For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls

Next
```

How can I retrieve them all in a For Each loop without an If/Then for every level in the stack?

EDIT:

```
Dim ctl As Control = Me
Do
    ctl = Me.GetNextControl(ctl, True)
    'Do whatever you have to ctl
Loop Until ctl Is Nothing
```

This is so far the best method I found of doing this.

Comment: That is the best I have found also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a method that `recursively` traverse containers inside the container. Something like this:

```
 Dim _list As New List(Of Control)
 Public Sub GetChilds(container As Control)
        For Each child As Control In container.Controls
            _list.Add(child)
            If (child.HasChildren) Then
                GetChilds(child)
            End If
        Next
 End Sub
```

To call this method:

```
 list=new List(Of Control)
  GetChilds(Me)
  For Each cntrl As Control In _list
    ....
  Next
```

Comment: GetNextControl returns controls that are in tab order. What if a control is not in tab order, is not enabled (grayed out) or is invisible? The recursive approach of AVD will always work.

Comment: I understand! Thank you, for the purposes of my application though, the disabled/invisible controls aren't an issue. If they become one I'll definitely use AVD's approach.